# Errant behavior in the {{each}} tag of jQuery Templates in Internet Explorer?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-templates

I am building a page using jQuery templates, but getting some inconsistent behavior in IE 8.

I have a checkbox element inside an {{each}} tag, but IE throws an error when I try to append a string to the id.

Here is the HTML fragment:

```
<script id="filters-template" type="text/template">
<div id="CoinsuranceFilters" class="filters">
<h4><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkall_coinsurance" onclick="checkClass(this, 'coinsurance_items');" class="checkall" /> Coinsurance</label></h4>
{{each Coinsurance}}
<div class="filteritem">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="${'Coinsurance_' + id}" {{if IsSelected}} checked{{/if}} class="coinsurance_items"/> ${ItemText}</label>
</div>
{{/each}}
</div>
</script>
```

IE reports: 'id' is undefined

If I change the id field to id="${id}" the error goes away (although it appears to render 2 checkboxes for every 1 it should).

This works with no problems in Chrome and FF 4

This page uses jquery 1.5.2 & jquery-ui 1.8.12

Here is the JSON object that gets passed into the template:

```
{
    "IndividualQuoteID": "539b9d05-0c78-4c27-b238-9edaaabfb389",
    "Coinsurance": [
        {
            "id": 267,
            "ID": 267,
            "IsSelected": true,
            "ItemText": "70%"
        },
        {
            "id": 266,
            "ID": 266,
            "IsSelected": true,
            "ItemText": "80%"
        },
        {
            "id": 265,
            "ID": 265,
            "IsSelected": true,
            "ItemText": "90%"
        },
        {
            "id": 264,
            "ID": 264,
            "IsSelected": true,
            "ItemText": "100%"
        }
    ]
}
```

(The id and ID values are there intentionally. This error occurs with any key I try to concatenate with a string inside the {{each}} block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used Jquery templates, but from what I see in your code shouldn't it be like this :

```
<script id="filters-template" type="text/template">
<div id="CoinsuranceFilters" class="filters">
<h4><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkall_coinsurance" onclick="checkClass(this, 'coinsurance_items');" class="checkall" /> Coinsurance</label></h4>
{{each Coinsurance}}
<div class="filteritem">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="Coinsurance_${id}" {{if IsSelected}} checked{{/if}} class="coinsurance_items"/> ${ItemText}</label>
</div>
{{/each}}
</div>
</script>
```

I don't see what the ${'Coinsurance_' + id} syntax would refer to. If i get it right you want the checkbox to have the html id 'Coinsurance_267'.

Comment: That looks like it did the trick - strangely that syntax is used all over the place in this app and this is the only place it has an issue (it works everywhere else... not sure why that syntax is getting used). Thanks!